# NHibernate mapping of type List<Point>

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a single property that I want stored in two separate mysql columns.

The property is defined as:

```
public virtual List<Point> Vertices { get; set; }
```

Point is System.Drawing.Point.

My database table has two columns that i want this one property saved into:

```
xarr VARCHAR(3000)
yarr VARCHAR(3000)
```

If Vertices contained the following points:

```
{1,2}
{3,4}
{5,6}
```

When the entity was saved by Nhibernate, i would like the

```
yarr column to be populated with "2,4,6"
xarr column to be populated with "1,3,5"
```

Please do not advise me on redesigning the database schema. To answer my question I would like to know the best way to achieve this in NHibernate, given the constraints above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will admit to not having used NHibernate, but can you just add two properties to the model class for the xarray and yarray strings

```
public string XArray { get { return string.Join(",", this.Vertices.Select(v => v.X.ToString())); } }
public string YArray { get { return string.Join(",", this.Vertices.Select(v => v.Y.ToString())); } }
```

and then persist those?

edit:
Alright, if I'm reading this correctly, it sounds like you want to create a VerticesType

```
public class VerticesType : IUserType
{
    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var retval = new List<Point>();
        var xCoords = ((string) NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0])).Split(",");
        var yCoords = ((string) NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[1])).Split(",");

        for(i = 0; i < xCoords.Length; i++)
        {
            retval.Add(new Point(int.Parse(xCoords[i]), int.Parse(yCoords[i])));
        }

        return retval;
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        var list = value as List<Point>;
        if( list == null )
        {
            NHibernateUtil>String.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index);
            NHibernateUtil>String.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index + 1);
            return;
        }

        NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, string.Join(",", list.Select(v => v.X.ToString()), index);
        NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, string.Join(",", list.Select(v => v.Y.ToString()), index + 1);
    }

    # rest of IUserType implementation here
}
```

Obviously with more error checking. Hope that helps.

Comment: ok, i can do this, but is there a better way to leverage the framework using a usertype? Is there something other than a user type i would use for this?